# Combining multiple series and creating a new one in a Pandas df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge, series

I have 5 pandas.series which I want to merge in a new one. How is this possible? eg. I have s1: en s2: gl s3: a s4: nd and I wanna make a new one s5: england

I have tried pd.concat, combine, append but nothing seems to be working.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you have series such as

```
s1 = pd.Series(['en' , 'b'])
s2 = pd.Series(['gla', 'ra'])
s3 = pd.Series(['nd' , 'zil'])
```

you can just `sum` them

```
>>> s1+s2+s3

0    england
1     brazil
dtype: object
```

---

If you have series such as

```
s1 = pd.Series(['e', 'n'])
s2 = pd.Series(['g', 'l', 'a'])
s3 = pd.Series(['n','d'])
```

You can just `join` them

```
>>> ''.join(s1.tolist()+s2.tolist()+s3.tolist())

'england'
```

or `sum` first

```
>>> s1.sum() + s2.sum() + s3.sum()
'england'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @RafaelC ! but what if I have ints like: s1 = pd.series([2018, 2017, 2016]) s2 = pd.series([0, 1, 2]) s3 = pd.series ([10.23, 22.33, 99.22]) ?? Thanks again!

Comment: What is the expected output for this case?

Comment: There are split strings in series (like the en,gl,a,nd example above which worked, thanks!) but also there are dates with year, hour, minsecond (like s1 = pd.series([2018, 2017, 2016]) s2 = pd.series([0, 1, 2]) s3 = pd.series ([10.23, 22.33, 99.22]). So the expected output should be a new series called let's say df['timestamp'] which will be 2018 0 10.23 , 2017 1 22.33 , 2016  2 99.22 etc.